# Modal Image Click with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm very new to programming and I'm trying to complete a lesson on a uDacity course that uses Modals through Bootstrap. Here is my code, I am not getting any results on my test page:

[image]

[image]

Comment: copy and paste the code into the question please, we're more likely to provide answers if we can copy & make changes over writing it from scratch

Comment: Also - what is the question?

Comment: Stack Overflow won't let me because I'm a brand new member